# Creating a 'loading...' animation frame to display as a method is being executed?

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jframe, loading

I have a FileFinder.java and a Loading.java class with a GUI. The FileFinder.java allows users to select a directory and search for a file in that directory. Now, with larger directories, the search takes a few moments to complete, and I don't want users to wonder if it's actually searching, so I am trying to display another frame (Loading.java).

Here is my code for when the Search button is clicked:

```
 private void searchButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        String dirName = "";
        String username = System.getProperty("user.name");

        if(cdriveButton.isSelected()){
            dirName = "C:/Users/" + username;
        }
        else if(pdriveButton.isSelected()){
            dirName = "P:";
        }
        else if(xdriveButton.isSelected()){
            dirName = "X:";
        }
        else if(customButton.isSelected()){
            dirName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(rootPane, "Enter the directory you would like to search in: ", "Enter Directory", HEIGHT);           
        }   

          String search = filenameText.getText();
          File root = new File(dirName);
          resultText.setText("");


        Loading show = new Loading();

        show.setVisible(true);

        displayDirectoryContents(root, search);

        show.setVisible(false);



    }
```

Here is the Loading.java:

```
public class Loading extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Loading
     */
    public Loading() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Please wait...");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(148, 148, 148)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(186, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(122, 122, 122)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(164, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Loading.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Loading.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Loading.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Loading.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Loading().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Everything works fine, except for one small issue: it is not displaying the GUI properly inside of the Loading frame. It pops up when I press the button as it should, and remains there until the search is finished, and closes properly, but it should be displaying a label that says "Please wait...". It is not showing that label, it just displays a blank white frame.

Edit1: Solution found below. Convert to JDialog pane instead of JFrame and add a SwingWorker:

```
        JDialog jDialog = new JDialog();
        jDialog.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        jDialog.add(new JLabel("Please wait..."));
        jDialog.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(150, 50));
        jDialog.setResizable(false);
        jDialog.setModal(false);
        jDialog.setUndecorated(true);
        jDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        jDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jDialog.setVisible(true);

       SwingWorker swingWorker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        displayDirectoryContents(root, search);
        return null;
    }
};
```

Comment: Maybe you should show us the `Loading` class...

Comment: @arizzle the code or an image? It's just a JFrame with a label that has the icon property set to an image.

Comment: The class you have posted works fine.

Comment: @arizzle if it worked fine I would not be posting this question.

Comment: Is this the complete `Loading` class? You mentioned that there are images too. Because yes, the class you have posted works fine, I have tested it. Also, it is generally bad practice to have multiple JFrames (which is what I am assuming you have done here). The same result could be achieved using a `JOptionPane`

Comment: @arizzle how can I display a JOptionPane momentarily without requiring a user to confirm (press Ok) to keep executing?

Comment: You've got a Swing concurrency issue -- please see edits to answer. And yes, you can close a JOptionPane in code if you desire. Simply search this site to see how (one of the answers to this has been written by me).

Comment: @levijoraan I will post an answer showing you how to use a JDialog instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
displayDirectoryContents(root, search);
```

You're running this on the Java event thread or EDT (event dispatch thread). When this takes more than a moment to run, it blocks the EDT and prevents it from doing what it needs to do, including showing your loading window (which incidentally should be a *dialog* window such as a JDialog and **not** an application window or JFrame).

The solution: run this method call in a background thread such as that given by a SwingWorker. Display your *dialog* window, and use a call back to notify you when the worker is done and thus when you should no longer display the loading dialog window.

For example, this:

```
String search = filenameText.getText();
File root = new File(dirName);
resultText.setText("");

Loading show = new Loading();
show.setVisible(true);
displayDirectoryContents(root, search);
show.setVisible(false);
```

could be changed to something like (note code not tested)

```
String search = filenameText.getText();
File root = new File(dirName);
resultText.setText("");

Loading show = new Loading();
show.setVisible(true);

// create our worker
new SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<>(){
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        displayDirectoryContents(root, search);
        return null;
    }
};

worker.addPropertyChangeListener(evt -> {
    if (SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE == evt.getNewValue()) {
        // you should also call get() on the worker allowing
        // you to capture and handle all exceptions it might throw
        show.setVisible(false);
    }
});

worker.execute();  // run the worker
```

For more, please check out: [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: I have converted it to a jDialog and am getting the same blank white frame. How can I use a SwingWorker?

Comment: @levijoraan: please see edits to answer, but especially read the tutorial link.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to @Hovercraft of eels answer for the solution to your problem.

As a side answer, it is bad practice to use multiple `JFrames`, instead I recommend you use a JDialog. See this example:

```
JDialog jDialog = new JDialog();
jDialog.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
jDialog.add(new JLabel("Please wait..."));
jDialog.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(150, 50));
jDialog.setResizable(false);
jDialog.setModal(false);
jDialog.setUndecorated(true);
jDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
jDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
jDialog.setVisible(true);
```

This will display the message "Please wait..." in a small grey box in the centre of the screen, with no close button or title bar.

It is also non-blocking due to the `setModal(false)` option. So other code can execute while it is displayed.

Comment: Yep, better to use a JDialog than have multiple JFrames. 1+

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it looks good, but the JDialog does not appear as soon as I add the displayDirectoryContents(root,search); method

Comment: Are you using a SwingWorker like @HovercraftFullOfEels recommended?

Comment: Im afraid this may go beyond my comprehension at this point, as I think the problem originates with the Event Dispatch Thread which I have 0 understanding of. Thanks for trying

Comment: I am not, I am not sure how to implement such a thing.

Comment: @arizzle: please don't do that.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels my apologies, I have changed it back, I will make edits to your answer instead.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I had a difficult time navigating your answer. I apologize. Good news though, arizzle,  your code worked great after I modified slightly. I will add solution above.